# How to know if JRadioButton is enabled in java

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

So my argument in my if statement below has to check if my JRadioButton is checked, but for some reason, even if it's not checked, the program still runs.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String actionCheck = Binary.userInput1.getText();

    if(Binary.binary.isEnabled() && actionCheck.matches("[01]+")){ // checks if its binary
        int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(actionCheck, 2);
        String convertedDecimal = Integer.toString(decimalValue);
        Binary.userInput2.setText(convertedDecimal);
    }

    else if (Binary.decimal.isEnabled() && decimalCheck(Binary.userInput1)){
        int binaryValue = Integer.parseInt(actionCheck);
        Binary.userInput2.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(binaryValue));
    }
    else
        Binary.userInput1.setText("WRONG INPUT! -- try again");


}
```

What am I missing?

The buttons are called binary and decimal (Yes i know, my class is called Binary also, newbie errors)

Comment: `Yes i know, my class is called Binary also, newbie errors)` - so change it. All editors have "change all" functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was found!

It's not `isEnabled()` that should be used in this case but the method `isSelected()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `yourJRadioButton.isSelected()` instead of `isEnabled()`.